# on duplicate key update in Yii active record

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii

how can i write this command using Yii active record

```
 INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Comment: You might find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004269/yii-insert-on-duplicate-update)

Answer (score -3):

```
  $model->Yourmodel::model()->findByPk($key);

  if($model){
      $model->value = $newvalue;

  }else{
      $model = new Yourmodel();
      $model->value = $newvalue;

   }

   if($model->save()){
     // do somethings
   }
```

Comment: This works only for indiscriminative create/update, not for handling duplicate entries for unique indexes.