# Use" INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" to insert multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, yii, insert-update

**My Table structure**

table: marks
[image]

**My objective:**
i want to insert or update multiple records with the condition

i am currently check by this query

1st step

```
SELECT * FROM `marks` WHERE `student` =115 AND `param` =1
```

2nd step

```
if 
    records found by matching above criteria i just update record by my new values 
else
    insert new record into my table
```

It gonna working fine . but i want to reduce code and optimize this into single query . its possible or not ?
I found this on MySQL docs **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** . if this is a solution . how can i achieve by query  ?

Note: i am using the **Yii framework**  . suggestion from Yii also welcome

**Edited:**
 This query does't not update the rows . but escape from insert working correctly

```
INSERT INTO marks(`student`,`param,mark`,`created`,`lastmodified`,`status`) 
VALUES 
(11,30,10,'00-00-00 00:00:00','00-00-00 00:00:00','U')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `mark`=VALUES(`mark`)
```

Comment: First step: create a unique index on (student, param), then just try to insert like you would , `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET mark=VALUES(mark)`

Comment: @Wrikken how to set the two column combination as a unique . because different students have same param's . both student and param combination only unique . i not to familiar with indexing . plese need more info . thanks

Comment: @Wrikken i edit my question . please review it . it does not update the existing record . but its skip the duplicate entry correctly. i add the unique index for the fields student and param .

Comment: `ALTER TABLE marks ADD UNIQUE (student, param);`, and then `INSERT INTO marks (student, param, mark, created) VALUES (11,20,10,NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET mark=VALUES(mark);` should work.

Comment: @Wrikken this problem solved . thank for your comment. its useful to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this article [Yii INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004269/yii-insert-on-duplicate-update). They suggest you don't use this feature. But i want it to use, so I extended from CDbCommand my own component and add method for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
public function insertDuplicate($table, $columns, $duplicates)
{
    $params=array();
    $names=array();
    $placeholders=array();
    foreach($columns as $name=>$value)
    {
        $names[]=$this->getConnection()->quoteColumnName($name);
        if($value instanceof CDbExpression)
        {
            $placeholders[] = $value->expression;
            foreach($value->params as $n => $v)
                $params[$n] = $v;
        }
        else
        {
            $placeholders[] = ':' . $name;
            $params[':' . $name] = $value;
        }
    }

    $d = array();
    foreach($duplicates as $duplicate)
    {
        $d[] = '`' . $duplicate . '` = VALUES(`'.$duplicate.'`)';
    }
    $sql='INSERT INTO ' . $this->getConnection()->quoteTableName($table)
        . ' (' . implode(', ',$names) . ') VALUES ('
        . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' . implode(', ', $d);
    return $this->setText($sql)->execute($params);
}
```

Usage example:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->insertDuplicate('user', [
   'id' => $this->id,
   'token' => $token,
   'updated' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
], ['token', 'updated']);
```

This command will create user with this parameters or update `token` and `updated` fields if record exists.

Comment: can you please give the example parameter for this function . $table, $columns, $duplicates how to pass these values

Comment: @RyanBabu sure, i added some example

Comment: before this any fields indexing needed? please review my question on edited section . that query does not worked . Where i did mistake i can't understand my problem here . your code is useful i know . i just run that sql alone . its not update the existing value . Thanks for your example. nice to implement

Comment: INSERT INTO marks(`student`,`param,mark`, `created`,`lastmodified`, `status`) there is a error: `param,mark` it must by 'param', 'mark'

Comment: I tried again alex but not get updated only 0rows affected . i updated my question

Comment: I find out my problem @alex thanks for your answer now i use your function . i am not update the other values .**`param`=values(`param`), `student`=values(`student`) ** This is no need here . both values are same . now its working

Answer (score -1):

Do not implement "**INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE**" in your programming as it is **MySQL specific**. When you migrate from MySQL to other Database your program cannot communicate with new Database as per the concept of [Database Abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer)

try like this

```
    function actionName()
    {
        $id=$_POST['marks']['id']; //Pick the ID from your form values
        $model = Marks::model()->findByPk($id); //Check the records in the Marks table
        if (!$model) //If not found create a new Model for insertion. If records are there it will update the model
            $model = new Marks();
        $model->attributes = $_POST['marks']; //Assign the form values to attributes
        $model->save();
    }
```

Comment: did you read his question? he said that he want do that in one query

Comment: thanks for your advice . my application does not need the DB change feature . i am also using this type of process. i want to change this into sql because of DB hit rate . The insertion rate is very high . This process look like slow for me .i need optimization.