# How to update a table with values from multiple selects with the same name?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a series of selects populated with mysql data.  Note: Day name is a label

```
Sunday    time_from    time_to
Monday    time_from    time_to
Tuesday   time_from    time_to
...
Saturday  time_from    time_to
```

In the database these are stored in a table called *availability* whose structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `staff_availability` (
  `staff_availability_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `staff_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `time_from_id` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_to_id` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`staff_availability_id`)
);
```

This table is linked to 2 other tables to get pretty user readable names and times but for the UPDATE / INSERT I wouldn't need those because the selects have their respective time_from_id etc as the value (Except the days which are labels)

My php runs 2 foreach loops - one for time_from and one for time_to which generates selects as follows:

```
<select id="time_from" class="form-control input-sm" name="time_from">

<option value="null">Not Available</option>
 <?php foreach ($this->time_slots as $time) {

     if ($time->time_slot_id == $availability->time_from_id) { ?>

          <option value="<?php echo $time->time_slot_id; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $time->time; ?></option>

     <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $time->time_slot_id; ?>"><?php echo $time->time; ?></option>

    <?php }
} ?>
</select>
```

The problem: $_POST['time_from'] and $_POST['time_to'] only return one value.  How would I return all 7 pairs of selects to update the 7 timeslots in the staff_availability table like this:

```
day_id    time_from_id    time_to_id
1         2               14
2         4               14
3         2               14
...
```

Comment: where are the POST values?

Comment: This may useful for you check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192197/use-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-to-insert-multiple-records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name your `<select>`s a little bit better, you can access all 7 of them.

`<select name="time_from[0]" ...>`

See point #3 in the [HTML FAQ](http://php.net/faq.html) in the PHP documentation for more details.